# Xcontext-receivers when using rules_kotlin (Bazel)

Tags: kotlin, bazel, kotlin-context-receivers

I'm struggling to add the kotlin compiler option `-Xcontext-receivers`.

From what I see [here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_kotlin/blob/master/src/main/starlark/core/options/opts.kotlinc.bzl), it's not possible to add the option (nor any extra option).